# Visualization not expected in safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, flexbox

Hi I would like to share the following code:

```
 <div class="row full-width full-height wrapper-container">

  <div class="row full-width" style="flex: 0 0 auto;">...Items here...</div>

  <div class="row full-width wrapper-fullfill" style="flex: 1 1 auto; margin-top: 0.5rem;">

    <div ng-class="showList" class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-lg-8 wrapper-container">

      <div class="row full-width dropdown-places-type-mobile">
        <div class="input-container col-xs-12 no-padding" style="display:inline-block;">
          <div class="text-info text-info-menu" type="text" dropdown-menu="placesType" dropdown-model="placeType">Tipo de espacios</div>
          <img src='../images/arrow-select-primary.png' class="input-icon-menu" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row full-width wrapper-fullfill" style="overflow-y:scroll; padding:0;">
        <div class="row col-xs-12">
          <div ng-repeat="place in places" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <div ng-include="'./views/items/place-card.html'">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div ng-class="showMap" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-4" style="overflow: hidden; padding:0;">
      <ui-gmap-google-map ng-if="showMapMobile" center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' options='map.options'>
        <ui-gmap-markers fit="true" models="placeMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" options="'options'">
        </ui-gmap-markers>
      </ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Here the css for wrapper-container and wrapper-fullfill:

```
.wrapper-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.wrapper-fullfill {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I have a flex wrapper-container and inside a wrapper-fullfill class to fullfill al the remaining space until cover all the div with the element.
The problem is that in Chrome and Firefox the behaviour is the expected one, but in Safari the nested wrapper-container is not working as expected.

I would like to know if you could help me to find a solution for that. I am really stuck on this.

Here you can find the full code of the page with the css and the html elements:
http://test.nomadespacios.com/#!/places

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you also set a height to `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: @LGSon yes I did

Comment: If the above doesn't help, we need a _minimal working code snippet_ that reproduce the issue, _within_ the question, and an external link doesn't qualify, as when it dies, so does this question.

Comment: @LGSon ok, the problem is that is not easy to create a snippet to reproduce the issue because the file depends on multiple data. But I try and I edit the question.